# Moment Generating Function of a Beta random variable.

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, control-theory, hypergeometric-function, moment-generating-functions

After getting some excellent [help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115661/moment-generating-function-of-a-nonlinear-transformation-of-an-exponential-rando) on this problem in the statistics SE, I am reformuluating my question.  Let me know if I should just delete it and ask a new one.

---

Let $V$ be a $Beta(\alpha,1)$ random variable, with density 
$$
g(v) = \alpha v^{\alpha-1},
$$
with $v\in[0,1]$.  Then the Moment Generating Function is a confluent hypergeometric function, with a number of possible representations:
$$
MGF_V(\alpha,1,t) = \int_0^1 e^{t v}g(v)dv,
$$

$$
MGF_V(\alpha,1,t) = 1  +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \prod_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac{\alpha+r}{\alpha+r+1} \right) \frac{t^k}{k!}
$$

$$
MGF_V(\alpha,1,t) = \alpha (-t)^{-\alpha} (\Gamma(\alpha) - \Gamma(\alpha,-t))
$$
Where $\Gamma(x,t)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.  There are many more, apparently.  My interest is in the Legendre Transform of $\log MGF_V$:
$$
I(s) = \sup_t t s - \log MGF_V(t)
$$
This is a cost function for an optimal control problem.  I need to evaluate it.  The first order condition of this optimization is 
$$
s- \frac{MGF'_V(t)}{MGF_V(t)}  =0 
$$
There doesn't seem to be a convenient way to solve this. I've done so numerically in Matlab using their implementations of the various different functions that can be used to calculate $MGF_V$, but have lots of numerical instability as the parameter $\alpha$ and $s$ vary. Basically, my question is, is there a convenient way to express or calculate 
$$
\frac{MGF'_V(t)}{MGF_V(t)} 
$$ 
that I have overlooked?  Some of the forums above are such that the derivative is easy to calculate - for example, using the representation as $\Gamma$ functions,
$$
MGF'_V(t) = \frac{\alpha e^t}{t} +\alpha^2(-t)^{-\alpha-1}(\Gamma(\alpha) - \Gamma(\alpha,-t),
$$
so that the ratio of interest is
$$
\frac{MGF'_V(t)}{MGF_V(t)} = \frac{-\alpha + \frac{e^t (-t)^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha) - \Gamma(\alpha,-t)}}{t}
$$
which is no harder to calculate than $MGF_V(t)$, but it is not obvious to me how to solve 
$$
s = \frac{-\alpha + \frac{e^t (-t)^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha) - \Gamma(\alpha,-t)}}{t}
$$ 
for $t$ other than numerically, and I often have trouble with the implementations of $\Gamma$ in Matlab.